# WordprocessingML for Office 2010

Tags: ms-word, xsd, ms-office

I have three files, an xml template, xsl transformation file, and an xsd data file, being used to auto file a form. Its presumably created using WordprocessingML.. Looking online it appears WordprocessingML was only in Office 2003, and not in 2010 or above, or am missing something?

Is there support for this in later Offices and I am just missing it? Or did Microsoft create a better way to do this and if so, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word 2003 had its own XML format; Word 2007, 2010 and later use WordML.

For custom transforms in Word 2010, see http://www.itechtalk.com/thread9012.html